# Navigation issues on Homepage of website

Tags: html, css, templates, mobile, navigation

I am building a website for a client based off of [THIS](http://html5up.net/zerofour/) template. You can view the website here: [https://www.retirementautopilot.com/capitalfinancial](https://www.retirementautopilot.com/capitalfinancial/). I just applied some changes to the home page and suddenly the dropdown navigation doesn't work. When you hover the mouse over "About" and "Services", a dropdown menu should appear. If you travel to any other page you will see the dropdown works, so I messed up something on the homepage.

How do I get the navigation to work on the homepage again?

Also, the site has a CSS style for screens smaller than 1000px and mobile devices. If you shrink the browser down really small you can see the mobile version of the website. On the homepage of my site, the mobile navigation doesn't work, but it works on every other page. I think these two issues are probably related. How can I get the dropdown and mobile navigation to work on my homepage?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
```

from my header on the index page and it worked again. It had nothing to do with me deleting anything. Rather, I already had jquery.min.js, which didn't work in conjunction with jquery.js.